# Android WebView disappears after closing interstitial video ad

Tags: android, admob, android-webview

I used [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) AdMob manual to add an interstitial advertisement to my app. The app has a `MainActivity` with a `WebView` for handling the game-play of a puzzle, and a top bar and navigation drawer for handling the navigation.

The interstitial works fine for text and image ads, but not for video ads. After closing a video ad, the `WebView` is gone (the top bar and navigation drawer are still there). If I then click on a menu item in the navigation drawer, which should navigate to a new page in the `WebView`, the app crashes with the following `NullPointerException` (tested on Android 4.2 and 6.0 device):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.bd.test.MainActivity.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.bd.test.MainActivity.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.design.widget.aa.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.m.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.design.internal.d.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:97)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The menu item click handler calls the `loadUrl` function of my `WebView` object `mWebView`, which is somehow set to `null` while showing or closing the interstitial video ad.

Could there be interference between two `WebView`'s; mine and the one that shows the interstitial ad (similar to what I [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412967/android-adview-interferes-with-click-handling-of-another-webview-in-the-same-act) earlier with banner ads)?

Or am I simply making a mistake in my code? The relevant parts of my `MainActivity` are given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected WebView mWebView;
    protected InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    protected int pageId = R.id.nav_home;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initToolbar();
        //initDrawer();
        //initNavigationView();

        initAdInterstitial();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        initWebView();
        navigate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        pageId = item.getItemId();
        navigate();
        return true;
    }

    protected void navigate() {

        // Close drawer if it is open.
        if(mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

        if(pageId == R.id.nav_home) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(URL_INDEX);
        }
        else if(pageId == R.id.nav_level0) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(getLevelUrl(0));
        }
        else if(pageId == R.id.nav_level1) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(getLevelUrl(1));
        }
        else if(pageId == R.id.nav_level2) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(getLevelUrl(2));
        }
        else if(pageId == R.id.nav_level3) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(getLevelUrl(3));
        }
        else if(pageId == R.id.nav_history) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(URL_LAST_PLAYED);
        }
    }

    protected void initWebView() {

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        // Deprecated.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Context c = mWebView.getContext();
            webSettings.setDatabasePath(c.getFilesDir().getPath() + c.getPackageName() +
                    "/databases/");
        }

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            /*
             * HERE IS WHERE THE INTERSTITIAL AD IS SHOWN.
             *
             * Shows the interstitial ad every n-th page load.
             */
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                // After WebView page is loaded:

                // Update page load count.
                navigationCount = (navigationCount + 1) % adFrequency;

                // Show ad once every n-th page load.
                if(navigationCount == 0) {
                    showAd();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void initAdInterstitial() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    protected void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void showAd() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is due to this line in `onCreate()`

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
```

When you return to your Activity you will have a non null savedInstanceState so will never initialise your WebView.

NB It helps if you de-obfuscate your stacktraces or publish source with the line numbers.

Comment: I know, I tried to get an de-obfuscated stacktrace, but I never got a video interstitial ad on my de-obfuscated debug version (only text and image, then it works fine). Therefore I currently only have the stacktrace from the obfuscated release version. But with the explanation I hoped is was clear that the variable mWebView is null when loadUrl is called in the navigate function.

Comment: And you're most probably right about the savedInstanceState (I overlooked that a little, inserted the if-statement based on some Fragment documentation but forgot to update it afterwards). I can only test it later today or tomorrow, I'll respond to the answer afterwards.

Comment: You were indeed right. It took a long time before a video ad showed up, but it finally did, and it worked! Thanks William!